# Writing string blob to file (XLSX templating with Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, openxml

I'm using the [xlsx-template](https://github.com/optilude/xlsx-template) library to generate Excel documents. I'm recreating the example from the github readme and I'm stuck on the first step - the standard templating function returns a 'string blob' representing the excel file.

How do I write a string blob to the file system in node?

Comment: Have you tried the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html)? If so what have you tried?

Comment: yes, checked the documentation - fs.write, fs.writefile, fs.writesync - no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
fs.writeFileSync(
    path.join(__dirname, 
    'templates', 
    'output.xlsx'), 
    data, 
    'binary', 
    function (err) { [...]
```

The third parameter, 'binary', was key.